# Why are subscripts not interpreted with the standard octave-4.0.0 graphics toolkit?

Tags: for-loop, printing, octave, subplot

I am relatively new to Octave, and I am having trouble saving a figure, consisting of a set of subplots generated with "for" loops.

To illustrate this issue, I have generated the sample code shown at the bottom of this post. After defining the independent (x) and dependent (y = 2*x) variables, a for loop goes from i = 1:4, and each time a random number vector (err) is generated with the randn function. On each step of the for loop, a subplot is generated, which contains: (a) original data (y) illustrated as a solid line; (b) random data (y + i*err) illustrated as coloured markers.

The subplots with their corresponding lines and markers are correctly generated by the GNU Octave interface, and the y-axis label format ylabel('f(x) = y, f(x) = y_{rand}') is also displayed as desired with string "rand" shown as a subindex.

However, when I try to save the figure with either the "print" or "saveas" functions for pdf or eps formats, only the random data (coloured markers) is kept and the yaxis label is explicitly displayed as: "f(x) = y. f(x) = y_{rand}", ignoring the formatting.

For reference, I am running Octave 4.0.0 on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, and the Linux OS is run from a virtual machine using Windows 8.1.

Thanks for your attention.

Vinicio

```
clf
clear all
clc

% Define the indepedent (x) and dependent (y) variables
x = 0:1:20;
y = 2*x;

% Allocate random error vector
err = zeros(1, length(x));
color = jet(4);

for i = 1:4

  % Generate random error vector with mean = zero, var = 1
  err = randn(1, length(x));

  subplot(2, 2, i)

    % Plot original data (y)
    plot(x, y, '-k', 'markersize', 9)
    hold on

    % Plot random data (y + err)
    plot(x, y + i.*err, 'ok', 'markerfacecolor', color(i, 1:end))
    hold on    

  % Edit plot
  set(gca, 'fontsize', 16)  
  ylabel('f(x) = y, f(x) = y_{rand}')
  xlabel('x')
  ylim([-10 50])
  hold all

end

% Set directory and save figure
cd ~/Documents/Octave;
saveas(gcf, "fig1.eps")
```

Comment: Is the for loop really relevant here ? Without a for loop, plots are saved correctly ?

Comment: Yes, the figure is correctly saved if the subplots are not created with a for loop, any suggestions?

Comment: No, this has nothing to do with the loop. If I comment out the `for` and `end` lines, and just set `i=1`, the bug is still there.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I did perform other tests in which the plot was saved correctly so I just got confused, sorry about that. So do you think this is a bug? Any ideas of how to fix this? I also sent this by email to the Octave support team but I have not received a response yet. If I get something, I will let you know. Sorry, and thanks again.

Comment: It's OK. Retitling to better reflect the bug at hand. It seems you are new to this stuff, so let me kindly stress that [Cross-posting should be avoided](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:Crossposting). Here is the [link to your question to the help-octave list](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/help-octave/2015-11/msg00141.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This wrong behavior can be reproduced in 4.0.0 with this shorter example:

```
axes
ylabel("f(x) = y, f(x) = y_{rand}")
```

It has been fixed in the current development version, so no need to file a bug report.

Meanwhile, as a workaround, `graphics_toolkit("gnuplot")` can be used.

Please remember to create a new `figure`, or to `close all`, before testing. Indeed, the previous [`graphics_toolkit`](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Graphics-Toolkits.html) is still used for the existing figures.

Comment: Got it! Thanks for everything! Have a nice day.

Comment: You're welcome. And please remember to send to the help-octave list a message stating that it is solved, with a link here, so that nobody loose time trying to answer an already answered question.